Getting AccessToKeyVaultDenied error in azure portal for function app, even though managed identity has roles KeyVaultReader and KeyVaultSecretsUser
I have set up a Function app in azure.  I have created a key vault in the same region.  I set the function app to use system managed identity.  I granted the KeyVaultReader and KeyVaultSecretsUser roles to the function app's managed identity.  (The Key vault is configured to use RBAC).  When I define an application setting which should be able to use a Key Vault Reference, my supposition is that I should see an absence of errors in the listing on the Azure portal.
However, a status of AccessToKeyVaultDenied persists.
In case it is relevant, I am creating a nodejs function app using typescript
Assumptions I have verified:

Key Vault and Function App are in the same region
Key Vault "bypass ... for trusted Azure ..." firewall setting is enabled
Function app is configured to use managed identity
Virtual network integration is enabled for the function app with a specific funcapp subnet
that same funcapp subnet is allowed in the key vault networking firewall settings

Things I have tried:

granting additional roles wrt key vault to the function app's managed identity (up to and including owner)

I am certain there is one key element I am overlooking that will rapidly resolve this, but my research into this problem hasn't turned anything up.
For reference:
Specific Key Vault References (de-identified) tried:
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)

I was also getting same error:

AccessToKeyVaultDenied
Key Vault reference was not able to be resolved because site was denied access to Key Vault reference's Vault


When KeyVault reference is used in vnet configured Function app you need to enable Microsoft.KeyVault service endpoint in the subnet which you are allowing in Key vault and also enable Exception.



This worked for me.
OUTPUT:




I have tried adding the Endpoint indivdually to both: subnet where KeyVault is and subnet where Function App is, but same error results.  I have verified: system-assigned managed identity for func app has KeyVaultSecretsUser role.  I assume that the subnet config you showed above is the func app subnet.  If so, the only difference seems to be that the func app subnet must be delegated to Microsoft.App/environments service.

@sfulbright_prae Service endpoint enabled in subnet which is used in keyvault. Not function subnet
